# Can I mix type commands with variables in batch?

Tags: batch-file

I am making a batch game, and I am making visual maps for it. Here's an example.

```
========
(Town)
========

                    [ ]                   
                     |                    
        [ ] - [ ] - [ ] - [ ] - [ ] - [ ] 
               |     |     |
              [ ] - [ ] - [ ] - [ ]
               |     |
        [ ] - [ ] - [ ] - [ ] - [ ]
                     |
                    [ ]

Current Location: %loc%
1) Go up

2) Go down

3) Go left

4) Go right
```

As you can see, I used `%loc%` at one point. I am planning to use `type` commands for this, but it always appears as is (`%loc%`). I have found nothing else that clarifies this. Will adding variables into a text document like this work at all (note that I am also planning to use variables in every space in the square brackets), and if not, is this map basic enough so that I can paste it directly into the editor with some `echo` commands (haven't tried, don't have the time just yet)? If neither of these work, is there anything else I can do to avoid making separate text documents for every location? If not, no worries.

Comment: "*Will adding variables into a text document like this work at all?*" - no. "*is there anything else I can do to avoid making separate text documents for every location?*" - a) do the replacement of text yourself. b) use a real programming language to do it because it's going to be approximately 0 fun in batch.

Comment: **1.** This will not work with `type` command in any way. **2.** If you use a `for /F "delims=" %%a in (theFile.txt) do echo/%%a` command instead, then you may do that just changing `%loc%` by `!loc!` in the file and inserting a `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` command at beginning of the program.

Comment: I've noticed that `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` seems to ignore the punctuation in echo statements. Is this true, and is there any way to stop it?

Comment: That command modify the way that the exclamation-mark `!` character is processed. If you want to show an exclamation mark, you must escape it with one caret if is enclosed in quotes: `echo "Hello, World^!"`, or with two carets if not: `echo Hello, World^^!`